# XML Restrict based on another element value

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Basically I have my XML version 1.0 and I have a complex element with following example:

```
<tile>
  <position>5</position>
  <type>floor</type>
  <towerPlacement>true</towerPlacement>
</tile>
```

I have defined following in my XML Schema:

```
<xs:element name="type">
   <xs:simpleType>
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:enumeration value="road"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="floor"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="startPos"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="endPos"/>
   </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Is there a way to make my `towerPlacement` true only if `type = floor`?

```
<xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="towerPlacement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Your constraint cannot be expressed in XSD 1.0.

### XSD 1.1

Your constraint *can* be expressed in XSD 1.1 using an assertion to state that `towerPlacement` must only be `true` if `type = 'floor'`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" 
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="tile">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="position" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="type">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="road"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="floor"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="startPos"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="endPos"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="towerPlacement" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="(type='floor' and towerPlacement='true') 
                       or towerPlacement!='true'"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to be working now. I had done this earlier but, managed to place the assert in wrong place :/

Comment: Nvm.. I placed the assert there and then complexType turned red with error saying it is invalid content. I don't know which XSD version I have since I auto-generated in IntelliJ. What do you think? @kjhughes