# Can I validate polymorphic XML elements based on a child Type element value?

Tags: xml, xsd, polymorphism, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I want to validate polymorphic `Shape` elements, differentiated by the `Type` child element (*not* attribute) value.  Below are sibling Circle and Rectangle `Shape` elements.  Circles have a `Radius` and only 1 `Point`.  Rectangles don't have `Radius` and have 4 `Point` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shapes>
  <Shape>
    <Type>Circle</Type>
    <ID>A1234</ID>
    <Label>This is round</Label>
    <Radius>5.4</Radius>
    <Points>
      <Point>
        <X>5.00</X>
        <Y>2.00</Y>
      </Point>
    </Points>
  </Shape>
  <Shape>
    <Type>Rectangle</Type>
    <ID>B4567</ID>
    <Label>This is not round</Label>
    <Points>
      <Point>
        <X>0.00</X>
        <Y>0.00</Y>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <X>4.00</X>
        <Y>0.00</Y>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <X>4.00</X>
        <Y>2.00</Y>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <X>0.00</X>
        <Y>2.00</Y>
      </Point>
    </Points>
  </Shape>
</Shapes>
```

Here's a NON-functional schema along the lines of what I was hoping to do:

```
  <xsd:simpleType name="ShapeTypeEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="Circle"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Rectangle"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:complexType name="ShapeBase">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Type" type="ShapeTypeEnum"/>
      <xsd:element name="ID" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Label" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="Shape" type="Circle">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="ShapeBase">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="Radius" type="xsd:decimal"/>
          <xsd:element name="Points">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Point" type="Point"/>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="Shape" type="Rectangle">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="ShapeBase">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="Points">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="4" maxOccurs="4" name="Point" type="Point"/>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="Point">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="X" type="xsd:decimal"/>
      <xsd:element name="Y" type="xsd:decimal"/>
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

The lines `<xsd:complexType name="Shape" type="Rectangle">` and `<xsd:complexType name="Shape" type="Circle">` don't work.  Is it possible to validate identically named elements with different schema sections based on the value of a child Element (`Type`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSD 1.0, it can't be done. In XSD 1.1, it can, using assertions.

Though even using assertions, it's not that easy (it would be much easier if `Type` were an attribute). You need to define a content model that's effectively a union of all the different models for different shapes (you can't use a simple `xs:choice` in this example because it would violate UPA), and then you need to define assertions like

```
<xs:assert test="exists(radius) = (type = 'Circle')"/>

<xs:assert test="count(points) = 4 or type != 'Rectangle'"/>
```

XSD 1.1 is supported in Altova, Saxon, and Xerces, but not for example by the Microsoft schema processor.

Comment: All true, but also worth pointing out that [***the XML design itself is essentially non-ideal***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57692764/290085).

Comment: That's true... but a lot of people design their XML first, and then try to retro-fit a schema later; and there's not really much wrong with this XML design if it weren't for the limitations of XSD.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Kay has explained how you might use `xs:assert` to achieve your requested validations, assuming that your XML design cannot be changed.  However, it's worth pointing out that your XML design itself is essentially problematic:

## *Generic element name plus type is an anti-pattern in XML*

### Bad

```
<Thing>
  <Type>TrueNature</Type>
  <!-- ... -->
</Thing>
```

XSD 1.1 and assertions are required to constrain based on `TrueNature`.

**See also:**

- [Vary type in XSD according to element value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52077040/290085)
- [XML Restrict based on another element value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47694183/290085)
- [Require XML element in XSD when another element has certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37071177/290085)

### Better

```
<Thing type="TrueNature">
  <!-- ... -->
</Thing>
```

XSD 1.1 and assertions or [Conditional Type Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27878402/290085) are required to constrain based on `TrueNature`.

### Best

```
<TrueNature>
  <!-- ... -->
</TrueNature>
```

XSD 1.0 suffixes because the element name itself reflects its true nature.